# Database project not showing in solution configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm editing solution configurations in Visual Studio 2010, and my database project is not showing up at all, so when I build it using MSBuild it is getting the wrong configuration.

Is this a known issue? Is there a way to make these types of projects show in the Visual Studio UI so I can assign them to configurations, or do I have to hack the solution file? (yuck)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'd already hacked the solution files to try and fix a separate build-related problem, so reverting specific changes fixed my problem.